# Ubuntu 20.04 on AMD Ryzen 5 pro 4650u + Integrated Graphics w/ Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: multiple-monitors

I believe this is a recurrent question, but I couldn't find an answer that was both up-to-date and satisfactory, so I will still ask it.

I just bought an HP Elitebook 845 G7 with AMD Ryzen 5 pro 4650u + Integrated Graphics and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. Before switching back to Linux, I have used Windows 10 for almost a decade and I had a double Eizo 24" setup, which worked flawlessly thanks to a high-end docking station I had from work.

I have been trying to reproduce the setup with the new notebook, albeit unsuccessfully since the docking station is apparently only compatible with Windows 10. I have tried to use one HDMI port and one HDMI-to-USB-C dongle for the second monitor and it also didn't work. I had another VGA-to-USB-A dongle, but it didn't help either.

What is the state-of-the-art in dual monitor connectivity with Linux on AMD? Does AMD require a different approach than Intel? (That was the second major change in my workflow).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be due to the compatibilty issues of Ryzen 4000 series CPU with the Linux kernel (less than version 5.7 or 5.8) in Ubuntu 20.04.

I faced similar issues with my Ryzen 4700U CPU laptop - which now works fine with Ubuntu 20.10 (Linux kernel 5.8).

Try using the docking station with Ubuntu 20.10 live environment - if that works,

- you could install [Mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) in your Ubuntu 20.04 (risky approach)
- Or switch to Ubuntu 20.10